# $1\,997^{2^{n}}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$ - proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have a problem with this:

Proove, that number $1\,997^{2^{n}}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$.

I tried mathematical induction, but I have a problem to proove the second step

$2^{n+2}$ /  $1\,997^{2n}-1$

$2^{n+2}2$ / $1\,997^{2}\, 1\,997^{2n}-1$

I just don`t know, how can I extract this expression $1\,997^{2n}-1$ from this $1\,997^{2}\, 1\,997^{2n}-1$

I think, that this might help:

$1\,997^{2n}-1$ = $(1\,997^{n}-1)(1\,997^{n}+1)$

$1\,997^{2}\, 1\,997^{2n}-1$ = $(1\,997^{n+1}-1)(1\,997^{n+1}+1)$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are dealing with $1997^{2^n}$, not $1997^{2n}$. Once you realize the difference you will see that induction, in fact, works.

Comment: @Wojowu I would say, that those two formulas are equivalent.

Comment: They are expressions, and no., $1997^{2^n} = 1997^{(2^n)}\neq (1997^2)^n$

Comment: They aren't. For example, $1997^{2^3}=1997^8$ is not the same as $1997^{2\cdot 3}=1997^6$. The problem is that $1997^{2^n}\neq (1997^2)^n$, as exponentiation is not associative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake seems to stem from mistaking $1997^{2^n}$ for $1997^{2n}$.

To answer the question, besides from using Euler's theorem, induction will also work. For $n=0$ we have

$$1997^1-1=2^2\cdot499$$

Now assume that $2^{n+2}k|1997^{2^n}-1$, that is $1997^{2^n}-1=2^{n+2}k$ for some integer $k$. Then we have

$$1997^{2^{n+1}}-1=\left(1997^{2^n}\right)^2-1=\left(1997^{2^n}-1\right)\left(1997^{2^n}+1\right)=\left(2^{n+2}k\right)(2^{n+2}k+2)=2^{n+3}k(2^{n+1}k+1)$$

So $2^{n+3}|1997^{2^{n+1}}-1$

Comment: thanks. Please, chceck if you don`t miss $-1$ in the last expression ($2^{n+3}|1997^{2^{n+1}}-1$) and $k$ in the last but one expression ($2^{n+3}k(2^{n+1}k+1)$).

Comment: @martina, yup, those were typos, thanks for catching them.